# fixed point of a contraction on a closed, convex space

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, banach-fixed-point

Let $C$ be a non-empty, closed, convex set of a normed linear space $E$. If $F: C \rightarrow C$ is a contraction(i.e. $\Vert F(x)-F(y) \Vert \leq L\Vert x-y \Vert $ where $0 \leq L <1 \thinspace \forall \thinspace x,y \in C$)

I want to prove $F$ has a unique fixed point in $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the uniqueness. If $F(x)=x$ and $F(y)=y$ then
$$\Vert x-y \Vert=\Vert F(x)-F(y) \Vert \leq L\Vert x-y \Vert.$$
Hint for the existence. If $E$ is complete then show that for $x_0\in C$, the recursive sequence $x_{n+1}=F(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and therefore it is convergent.

Comment: Here $E$ is not complete.

Comment: @Manu Rohilla If $E$ is not complete then I think that the existence of the fixed point does not hold.

Comment: can you please give an example where fixed point theorem does not hold?

Comment: @Manu Rohilla $F(x)=x^2$ is a contraction in $C=(0,1/2)$ with no fixed point. I'm trying to find a counterexample with $E=C$ a not-complete normed linear space.